# How would one describe a sound of boredom?

Tags: american-english, writing, sounds, onomatopoeia, gestures

Specifically, if a person gave a heavy short and gruff sigh, and said. "I'm booooorrrrreeeeed!" then made a sound that kinda had "uuuugggghhhhh" in it but as more of a sigh.

How could that be described? It's not quite "sighing" or "huffing" but a kind of mix with a gruff-ish sound added to it. I could simply say the person "complained" but that seems a little too basic, which sometimes is okay but in this case I want something specific that describes the emotion, or is there no exact word for that?

"Hhhuuugh!"

Comment: Lovely question. I'm not sure it could be spelled but might be better expressed by a description of a sound or action of the sufferer.

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you looking for the sound/onomatopoeia of the sound, or are you looking for the name of the sound? Some of the answers give one, and some the other.

Comment: Depending on your needs, questions like this might be better asked on [writing.se].  It's not _off-topic_ here, but the two sites may give quite different perspectives, because of the different assumptions about your needs.

Comment: ZZZZZzzzzZZZ...

Answer (score 13):

I'd describe that as a "groan"

Comment: Yeup that was the word I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

There are many verbs and adjectives you could use here! Assuming you are using show-not-tell, a way to describe something like this could simply be to detail the actions of this character. For example,
*"She taps her fingers loudly on the table and lets out a large sigh every now and then, even standing up and checking her phone for a Wi-Fi signal,"*
makes it easier to see the character is impatient and bored, versus
*"She sighs loudly."*
Alternatively, simple verbs are acceptable in passage summaries. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot. Sometimes just need something to make the ol noggin think

Answer (score 5):

***Blarg*** (*blargh, blerg*) and ***argh*** are often used as an interjection to express boredom. However, these onomatopoeic words would convey the intended feeling within the context as they can be used to express many other feelings like frustration, disappointment, angst etc. They are also used as sounds effects in mangas, comics; and in the subtitles of animes, cartoons.

*[Urbandictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Blarg)* has some good definitions of *blarg*:

> Blarg is a unique word, being the only word that not only means anything you want it to, or is used to show disinterest or boredom, but also is ,the only word that thousands upon thousands of people have claimed to have made up but has been around since man discovered they could use tools.
>
> ---
>
> **1.** A sigh of complete angst/depression.
>
> **2.** A sigh of boredom
>
> *1. Blarg, someone in heaven created me only to laugh at my misery...* 
> *2. Wow, I am so bored...blarg...*
>
> ---
>
> A combination of "blah" and "argh," generally used to describe boredom or frustration.

The definition of *argh* from *[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/argh)*:

> *(onomatopoeia)* Expressing annoyance, dismay, embarrassment or frustration.
>
> **Usage notes:** 
> Any of the letters may be reduplicated, e.g. *Arrggh!, Aaaarrrggghhh!*

Answer (score 4):

A common sound expressing boredom is traditionally written as "ho-hum". [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/ho-hum) defines it as "(an exclamation expressing boredom, weariness, or contempt.)" It can also be used as an adjective, meaning "boring".

The [Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/87645) (may be paywalled) has its earliest example from 1924, and has the same definition: "int.   (usually as an expression of boredom). Also as n.v. As adj., dull and routine."

Answer (score 3):

The action could perhaps be described as a **moan** - the word can describe a low, drawn out noise, but can also be used more generally as a synonym for complaining without making any particular sound (although it does evoke a particular tone of voice).

Comment: Yea....I avoid that word. People tend to...misinterpret if you know what I mean...BAHAHAHA, not funny, anywho thanks for the suggestion anyways.

Answer (score 0):

***Meh*** is an interjection that can express boredom. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meh) explains that it

> is a *colloquial interjection used as an expression of indifference or boredom*. It is often regarded as a verbal equivalent of a ***shrug of the shoulders***. The use of the term ***"meh"*** shows that the speaker is apathetic, uninterested, or indifferent to the question or subject at hand. It is occasionally used as an adjective, meaning something is mediocre or unremarkable.

If you read this article prompted by the pandemic, *[There’s a Name for the Blah You’re Feeling: It’s Called Languishing](https://www.nytimes.com/2021/04/19/well/mind/covid-mental-health-languishing.html)*, from *The New York Times*, you'll find this sentence:

> In the past year, many of us also have been struggling with interruptions from kids around the house, colleagues around the world, and bosses around the clock. ***Meh***.